# 404 Error In AngularJS

Tags: html, json, angularjs

Hi I am new to AngularJS. I startted with [this tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05). In tutorail `$http.get` method is invoking a JSON file. In my case I always getting 404 Error. Location of JSON file is also relative with HTML file. But getting the same error always.

Here is my code:
index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My HTML File</title>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
 Total Number of phones: {{phones.length}}
 Search: <input ng-model="query">
 Sort by:
<select ng-model="orderProp">
  <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
  <option value="age">Newest</option>
</select>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
  {{phone.name}}
  <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

controllers.js

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
$http.get('phones.json').success(function(data){
$scope.phones = data;
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
alert('data = ' + data + ' status = ' + status);
});
}
```

All the files in same directory(index.html, controllers.js, phones.json). What am I missing here? Why it is throwing 404 Error?

Below is the attached screenshot of browser:
[image: Below is the attached screenshot of browser:][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0biE.png)

Comment: open firebug and see where is it fetching your json from.

Comment: try absolute url with http://pull path

Comment: This probably has to do with the way your web/application server is set up. Which server environment do you use? Can you show your directory structure? Can you access the file using a browser or curl?

Comment: @gae123 I am using simple html file. Without any Web/App Server. Yes I can access this JSON file via browser. But not accessible via tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter if the files are in the same directory. You need a server to host the files and that respond to the GET, POST PUT and other http requests.

The very first step of the tutorial requests you to set up a server. See the section titled "Working with code" in the [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial). See the comments / discussions for that step too to get more information on setting up the server.

If nodeJs seems to be too difficult to use, then a simple Python server will also do. You could also use Apache / WAMP / XAMP server as well.

Without having a server set up, you cannot work on building the application described in the tutorial since the http requests will fail - the 404 error is thus obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this. I think the problem is your web server is not configured to server the JSON MIME type. If you are using IIS Express (and Visual Studio) see how to add the JSON MIME type to IIS.

http://michaellhayden.blogspot.ca/2012/07/add-json-mime-type-to-iis-express.html

Answer (score 2):

MIME type for JSON needs to be added to the IIS server.

For IIS go to your website, then MIME types and add

File name extension: .json

MIME type: application/x-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't related to angular, it means you are requesting a file that isn't where you(or your script) think it is.
Depending on the browser you are using, for example in chrome, open the inspector(right click,inspect element) and check in the console in the 404 error the full path of the file your application is trying to fetch, then check in your server that you actually have that file in that directory. You can also check in the network tab every request made by your application to get more information about the possible cause of the problem.
I see you are not using a server, then your address bar should say something like `file:///path/to/index.html` and the file with the 404 error probably has a path like `file:///angular.js` which should be `file:///path/to/angular.js`.
**EDIT**: If the file with 404 is `file:///angular.js` it means the browser is looking the file in the root directory of your system not in your current directory, then try to use relative paths like `<script src="./angular.js"></script>`.
I also think you will have *Cross origin requests* problems with the ajax request to `phones.json`. That's why I recommend you to setup a local server instead.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem of file path. I checked in inspector also. It is trying to read at correct directory where it exist. But it worked when we run it on server. Please see attached screenshot. Do you want to say any comment on it?

Comment: You should keep developing with a server, it tries to do an ajax OPTIONS request to a `file://..` address which isn't allowed. Only http requests are allowed for security reasons. Imagine a web page getting any file on your disk.

Answer (score -1):

You did not include any module in your html file.