# AngularJS giving 404 error on first run

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I have written a very basic AngularJS script to parse JSON response. When I run this, I get a 404 status (error), while it works fine after that. I have been able to replicate this behavior on Google chrome and Opera while it works fine on Firefox.

What could be the problem?

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <form name="saveTemplateData" action="#">
        First name:<br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.firstname"><br/><br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.firstname1">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submitForm()" />
    </form>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
            {{friend.name}}, {{friend.house_no}}
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>  
    <script src = "step4.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {
        firstname: "default",
        firstname1: "default"
    };

    $scope.save = function () {
        formData = $scope.form;
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        console.log("posting data....");
        $scope.formData = $scope.form;

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/testjson.php',
            params: {
                firstname: $scope.formData.firstname,
                firstname1: $scope.formData.firstname1
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            //var pretty;
            $scope.friends = data.response.docs;
            //angular.toJson(data, [pretty]);
            var str = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
            //document.write(str);
            alert("success");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(status);
        });
    };
});
```

The PHP file just returns a dummy JSON file

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $state = $_GET['firstname'];
    $state1 = $_GET['firstname1'];

    $arr = '{
        "response": {
            "numFound": 1,
            "start": 0,
            "docs": [
                {
                    "name": "'.$state.'",
                    "house_no": "76"
                }
            ]
        }
    }';

    echo $arr;
?>
```

EDIT:

*Some further Problem Diagnosis:*

- The problem is with both local and global URLs (working URLs with cross domain access allowed)
- When I enter a value in textbox and submit, a 404 error is received and the page is refreshed. But if I re-submit the form again with the same information the results are shown. This probably means that the results are fetched but somehow a 404 error is shown in the first execution of get request. Since, above is the entire code I have, I am not able to determine where the problem lies.
- There are no errors in the console. In the network tab, following details are there

  Method:GET

  Status: Cancelled

  Initiater: angular.js:8081

  Time:Pending

Comment: Think it's port error. See my reply - it's because you usually do not launch localhost in root, so it's not bound to the standard HTTP port at 80 or HTTPS at 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the tutorials on angularJS seem to leave the action field empty, but rather it turned out that action field is not required at all.

The issue is with the line

```
<form name="saveTemplateData" action="#">
```

It should rather be

```
<form name="saveTemplateData">
```

Additional help received from [AngularJS Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6506).

Answer (score 0):

Are you serving the html/js from the filesystem?
i.e. file:///angular-test.html

If so you might be hitting a cross origin problem. See [this other question about angular and 404s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505145/404-error-in-angularjs) for a possible answer.

Comment: yes I am using it from a file system but I have added the access control allow origin in my response header

Answer (score 0):

You are running this locally, correct? You need to add a port to your localhost, in the HTTP call in the controller:

(protocol)://localhost:XXXX/

MAMP/LAMP is usually port 8888 (your PHPs stack)

Cheers and <3 angular

Comment: It doesn't work only on the first run. After that it works perfectly with the code in the question

Comment: Paste all the console errors and network tab errors in the question maybe? Define 'first run' - full page refresh or...? I'll take another look