# 404 Error In AngularJS on a hosted server

Tags: webserver, web-hosting

I know my issue is very similar to this one : [404 Error In AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505145/404-error-in-angularjs?lq=1)

I understand why the error is happening in the tutorial, I also followed it, but for a different project I tried to do the same thing, and I hosted my application with my website : http://azilizblanchet.fr/CameleonCatalogue/#/services

The browser can't display the content because it can't find the .json files. Do you know how can I fix this ? I don't understand much when it comes to server ...

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: But there's no json here: http://azilizblanchet.fr/CameleonCatalogue/cases/services.json Are you sure it's the right path?

Comment: You're right, I don't see it in my browser either, but in Filezilla I can see the json in the right directory. Do you think it is a probleme with my hosting service ?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Some access settings, perhaps? You can change the tag for your question, because it's not angular related.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help, just one more advice, what tag should I use ?

Comment: You could try webserver, web-hosting